# Showing Section Name in Each Frame (Org-Mode Beamer)

Tags: org-mode, beamer

Roughly, I have:

```
#+options: H:2

* Introduction
** Some definition
    + list item1
    + list item2
```

This shows `Some definition` as its own beamer frame (with `+ list item1..`).

**Question:** How can I have, atop each beamer frame, the section title also? This way I would get a slide that shows something like `Introduction` and `Some definition` at the top (i.e., a slide with two titles), with `+ list item 1...` below.

Comment: I think this is a beamer question, not emacs's. See maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/145004/beamer-short-section-titles-in-headline

Answer (score 1):

How about something like the following in the preamble?

`#+latex_header: \setbeamertemplate{frametitle}{\insertsection~\\\insertframetitle}`

`#+latex_header: \makeatletter`

`#+latex_header: \CheckCommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}`

`#+latex_header: \renewcommand*\beamer@checkframetitle{\global\let\beamer@frametitle\relax\@ifnextchar\bgroup\beamer@inlineframetitle{}}`

`#+latex_header: \makeatother`